# My URL Parameter forwarding script isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-parameters

My problem is simple, I have some links in my page and I want them to be updated according to the URL parameter the user used to enter the site, basically I want the URLs present in my HTML page to be updated dynamically

```js
function getCookieValueByRegEx2(a, b) {
  b = document.cookie.match("(^|;)\\s*" + a + "\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)");
  return b ? b.pop() : "";
}
//BETFINAL
var PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL = $("#PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL").attr("href");
var replaced_PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL = PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL.replace(
  "/1?cid=fbc_",
  "/1?cid=fbc_" + getCookieValueByRegEx2("_fbc")
);
$("#PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL").attr("href", replaced_PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL);
$("#PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL").on("click", function() {
  window.location = replaced_PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<area
 id="PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL"
 target="_self"
 alt="BetFinal"
 title="BetFinal"
 href="https://record.gotobetfinal.com/v2/text/60/56/d391859f-f32f-11ec-88a6-2eb982ce984b/1?cid=fbc_" 
 coords="0,1000,1080,3150"
 shape="rect"
 onclick="dataLayer.push({'event':'banner-click','eventCategory':'click','eventAction':'banner-click'});"
/>
```

For some reason the script isn't working

Comment: @DiegoD because the its father tag is a map tag

Comment: I removed that comment minutes ago because it was dumb indeed :)

Comment: If you want to propagate the URL parameters, why are you looking in the cookies?

Comment: Use `window.location.search` to get the URL query parameters.

Comment: @Barmar It's returning the URL so there is no problem there

Comment: You shouldn't need the `click` handler in jQuery, since that's what clicking on an area does automatically.

Comment: If you do `console.log(replaced_PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL)` do you see the desired URL?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAhmed may I ask what's actually not working in your real scenario? I mean apart some details like what has been pointed out just now that you don't need to deal with the click event if you replaced the href attr already. It should work. You could for example try to strip down the problem first seeing if changing the href with a static string will work? Because maybe the issue is how you are dealing with the cookies

Comment: @Barmar No it actually shows that error  ReferenceError: replaced_PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: That doesn't make sense, you defined it right there. The `console.log()` should be right after the `var replaced_PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL =...` line

Comment: You have jQuery `.on("click")` and a `onclick=""` attribute. Use one or the other. Since you use jQuery already don't use the attribute

Comment: Since you are just appending to `PROMO_NEW_BETFINAL` use a `+=` instead of the `.replace()`